# What is derivative of $\sin ax$ where $a$ is a constant?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, differential

What is the derivative of $\sin a x$ where $a$ is a **constant**.

---

Actually, I'm studying Physics and not so well-versed with calculus. So, I have studied the basic rules of calculus but am stuck here.

I somewhat know about the product rule but don't get what to do if a constant is given in a trigonometric function, be it $\sin ax $ or $\cos ax$. Whatever..
Please help me get my concept clear.

---

Thank You!

Comment: Apply the chain rule.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT**

Recall that by chain rule

$$\frac{d}{dx}[\sin (f(x))]=\cos (f(x))\cdot f'(x)$$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{array}{c}
\frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {\sin ax} \right) = \left( {\cos ax} \right)\frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {ax} \right)\\
 = \left( {\cos ax} \right) \cdot a \cdot \frac{{dx}}{{dx}}\\
 = \left( {\cos ax} \right) \cdot a \cdot 1\\
 = a\left( {\cos ax} \right)
\end{array}

Comment: Out of interest why can you not just go straight from the first line to the last line without needing to have the $dx/dx$ part in there too?

Comment: @Chris - because going straight from the first line to the last is simply skipping over steps that are required by a *direct* application of the theorems, but are so trivial people usually don't bother to write them down. Krishna Srivastav has simply chosen to show all the steps to make it clear how the full calculation proceeds.  Occasionally a good teacher has to do this, as what makes those steps trivial is that everyone understands them. However, this is not always true of new students.

Answer (score 1):

Derivative of $\sin(ax) = a \cos(ax)$ by Chain Rule.